# JSPDF .html() function returning blank pdf page

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, jspdf

Using the new jsPDF .html() pretty much pulled straight from their docs, but it still results in a blank page:

Results in blank page:

```
function saveDoc() {
  window.html2canvas = html2canvas
  const doc = document.getElementById('doc')

  if (doc) {

        var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4')
        pdf.html(doc.innerHTML, {
           callback: function (pdf) {
             pdf.save('DOC.pdf');
           }
        })
  }
}
```

Results in no PDF generated:

```
function saveDoc() {
  window.html2canvas = html2canvas
  const doc = document.getElementById('doc')

  if (doc) {

        var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4')
        pdf.html(doc.innerHTML, {
           function (pdf) {
             pdf.save('DOC.pdf');
           }
        })
  }
}
```

Also results in blank page:

```
function saveDoc() {
  window.html2canvas = html2canvas
  const doc = document.getElementById('doc')

  if (doc) {

        var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4')
        pdf.html(doc, {
           callback: function (pdf) {
             pdf.save('DOC.pdf');
           }
        })
  }
}
```

Will use another tool if there are any other suggestions. Need it to be secure and generate selectable text PDF to keep overall size down. It's a long document it's generating and when doing it via addImage() the resulting file is huge. Thoughts?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After trying whole day came with following solution. I think we are getting blank page because of versions of html2canvas. I was using updated **jspdf**(1.5.3) with **html2canvas**(1.0.0-rc.3). Due to this I was getting blank pdf. When I use html2canvas(**1.0.0-alpha.12**) with jspdf(1.5.3) I am getting pdf with contents(not blank). So better to change version of html2canvas in order to work with newly .html() method.

```
 // scripts included
 <script type="text/javascript" src="html2canvas.js"></script> // 1.0.0-alpha.12 downloaded

 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.5.3/jspdf.debug.js" integrity="sha384-NaWTHo/8YCBYJ59830LTz/P4aQZK1sS0SneOgAvhsIl3zBu8r9RevNg5lHCHAuQ/" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

//html  
<div id='doc'>
    <p>Hello world</p>
    <div class="first-page">
        <h1>bond</h1>
        <img src="1.png"/>
    </div>
    <div class="second-page">
        <img src="2.png"/>
    </div>
</div>
<button onclick="saveDoc()">click</button>

// javascript

 <script type="text/javascript">
    var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');

    function saveDoc() {
        window.html2canvas = html2canvas
        const doc = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];

        if (doc) {
            console.log("div is ");
            console.log(doc);
            console.log("hellowww");



            pdf.html(document.getElementById('doc'), {
                callback: function (pdf) {
                    pdf.save('DOC.pdf');
                }
            })
       }
     }
   </script>
```

[html2canvas 1.0.0 alpha.12](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/releases/download/v1.0.0-alpha.12/html2canvas.js)

[.html() not working github](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/2487)

Comment: I bet this is completely it! I ended up running into a couple of other issues which required me to use a different PDF generation system for this project (not jspdf), but this makes sense that it would be html2canvas version that is the culprit. Thank you so much for digging into this!

Comment: Dude...you saved me from throwing my laptop out the window. Thank you.

Comment: Ok Will try again & let you know @FiddleFreak

Comment: Subscribing to the Promise solved this for me `pdf.html(doc).then(() => pdf.save('test.pdf'));`.

Comment: Would you still suggest this solution @PALLAMOLLASAI ?

Answer (score 13):

For me the working solution was to add the callback/promise behavior ---  `pdf.html(doc).then(() => pdf.save('fileName.pdf'));` Seems that html() method works async and the file to be downloaded was not ready when downloading based on the other example --- that's why it was empty.