# Generate PDF from HTML in Wordpress and get blank PDF

Tags: wordpress, jspdf

I have a WordPress-site and I would like to generate a PDF with [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF). It works, but the PDF is blank. I have set up another Page without WordPress and there it works with the same code. The sample that I use to code is in [codepen](https://codepen.io/amkid/pen/qKYwXo), but I'm not the author. Now my question, can it be, that jsPDF didn't work with WordPress? If yet, where is my Error?

functions.php

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'pdf', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/generatePDF.js', array( 'jquery' ),'',true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'jsPDF', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.4.1/jspdf.debug.js', array( 'jquery' ),'',true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'jsPDF-autotable', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf-autotable/2.3.4/jspdf.plugin.autotable.min.js', array( 'jquery' ),'',true );on 04.03.2021
```

myCustomTemplate.php

```
<div id='a4' style='height: 297mm; width: 210mm; border: 1px black solid; margin-left:20%;'>
    <p>Content of PDF</p>
</div>
```

generatePDF.js

function exportPDF() {
var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4');

```
var specialElementHandlers = {
    '#getPDF': function(element, renderer){
    return true;
    },
    '.controls': function(element, renderer){
    return true;
    }
};

doc.fromHTML(jQuery('#a4').get(0), 15, 15, {
    'width': 170, 
    'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
});

doc.save('offerte.pdf');
```

}

Comment: Please refer to this answer [JSPDF .html() function returning blank pdf page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57376671/jspdf-html-function-returning-blank-pdf-page)
Also, you can check this issue as well [The jsPDF HTML module generates a blank page](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/2571)

Comment: @Bhautik Thanks, but I used html2canvas and I need a option how I can generate a PDF with text and not as a picture.

Answer (score 0):

I think you also need to add this line of code before enqueue:

```
wp_register_script( 'jsPDF', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/2.3.1/jspdf.umd.min.js');
```