# (JavaScript/Typescript) Convert multiple HTML strings to multiple PDF documents and .zip save them

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, pdf-generation, jspdf

I am trying to figure out the best way to convert multiple HTML strings to PDFs (client side), add those to a .zip file (preferably using JSZip) and then downloading that .zip file.

Here is some code to try and accomplish this...

```js
// HTML examples to render
var tableHtml = `<table>
    <tr>
      <th>Company</th>
      <th>Country</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
      <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
      <td>Mexico</td>
    </tr>
  </table>`
var boldHtml = "<p> Hello <strong>World</strong> </p>"
var imageHtml = `<h1> City </h1>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1582010905429-bef463482aa2?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1000&q=80">`

var htmlToConvert = [tableHtml, boldHtml, imageHtml];

// Convert (using jsPDF, but totally open to other options... As this doesn't work)
let fileNumber = 1;
for (const html of htmlToConvert) {
      let jsPdf = new jsPDF();
      jsPdf.html(html); // This right here seems to be what I can't get working...

      zip.file(`file${fileNumber}.pdf`, jsPdf.output('blob'), { binary: false });

      fileNumber++;
}

// Save .zip file
const blob = await zip.generateAsync({ type: 'blob' });
const fileSaver = await import('file-saver');
fileSaver.default.saveAs(
      blob,
      `example.zip`
);
```

This code doesn't work, I think it's specifically the line `jsPdf.html(html)` that doesn't work. Once the .zip downloads there are 3 PDF files, but they are all blank with no content.

If I replace `jsPdf.html(html)` with `jsPdf.text(html, 1, 1)` that seems to work, but it's just plain html, so nothing is rendered. I did take a look at this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57376671/jspdf-html-function-returning-blank-pdf-page) and downgraded accordingly, but with no luck.

```
    "html2canvas": "1.0.0-alpha.12",
    "image-conversion": "^2.1.1",
```

jsPdf.html does have a callback option on it, so I also tried the following code:

```js
pdf.html(document.body, {
        callback: function (pdf) {
          zip.file(`file${fileNumber}.pdf`, pdf.output('blob'), { binary: false });
        }
});
```

However, the problem here is that the callback probably isn't being triggered until after the zip file saves, so the .zip will just be empty. Not sure exactly how to utilize the callback in this case? I might just be missing something obvious here.

I am open to using tools other than jsPdf to accomplish this task, any ideas?

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you need to wait for the all the conversions to complete before you save the zip file. You can do this by wrapping the callback in a Promise in order to work with your existing `await`s:

```
await Promise.all(htmlToConvert.map((html, fileNumber) => {
    const jsPdf = new jsPDF();
    return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
        jsPdf.html(html, {
            callback: function (pdf) {
              zip.file(`file${fileNumber}.pdf`, jsPdf.output("blob"), { binary: false });
              resolve(); // maybe reject if jsPdf is able to signal some kind of error condition?
            },
          });
    })
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

In comments I suggested this may not be the method to use with a zip function since all PDF contents are transported via the html to the clients device for generation in their cpu and local resources. In fact I was surprised to see the external image in file 3 was not blocked by CORS policy.

The generation of 3 files in one run triggers a response from the browser requesting allow multiple downloads thus this multi generate files is not ideal as the downloads after the 1st need to be reselected from download dialog.

However to provide a direct answer to your core question

> `doc.html({html}); // This right here seems to be what I can't get working...`

here is a draft to work from.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang=en>
      <head>
        <title>Title of the document</title>
<style>
</style>
      </head>
      <body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.5.3/jspdf.debug.js" integrity="sha384-NaWTHo/8YCBYJ59830LTz/P4aQZK1sS0SneOgAvhsIl3zBu8r9RevNg5lHCHAuQ/" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.js"></script>

<script>
 //

// HTML examples to render BEWARE sub canvas .css defaults mess with scales thus styles/widths may not be as expected the common div wrapper value ${html} below may need tweaking
var Html1 = '<table><tr><th>Company</th>&nbsp;<th>Country</th></tr><tr><td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>&nbsp;<td>Germany</td></tr><tr><td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>&nbsp;<td>Mexico</td></tr></table>'
var Html2 = '<p>Hello<strong> World</strong></p>'
var Html3 = `<h1> City </h1><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1582010905429-bef463482aa2?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=460&q=80">`
var htmlToConvert = [Html1, Html2, Html3];

// Convert (using jsPDF, but totally open to other options... As this doesn't work)
// set counter to 0
let fileNumber = 0;
for (const html of htmlToConvert) {
 fileNumber++;
   var doc = new jsPDF({
      orientation: 'p',

// unit MUST be pt for .html inclusion
      unit: 'pt',

      format: 'a4'
    })

// remember these values are printers point sizes not mm or pixels
    doc.setFontSize(10);

// optional heading text, x(pt), y(pt), var, var, 'alignment' NOTE variable fileNumber set above works for the heading
    doc.text(`File ${fileNumber}`, 298,  10, null, null, 'center');

// doc.html({html}); // This right here seems to be what I can't get working...

// Convert HTML to PDF in JavaScript ensure the file names are different
let name = `File${fileNumber}`
    doc.html(`<div style=width:1350px>${html}</div>`, {
        callback: function(doc) {
                  
                   doc.save(`${name}.pdf`);
        },
        x: 10,
        y: 10
    });
}
</script></body></html>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]